# How to wait for a page reload in Laravel integration testing

Tags: php, laravel, testing

We have a action to edit the user profile which redirects to the same page.
Here seePageIs() does not seem to wait for the new page to load.

The following test fails, as the new user name is not found in the response. When we load the profile page manually after the test, it was updated properly.

```
public function testCanEditUserProfileAsConsumer()
{
    $this->loginConsumer();

    $this->visit('/user/profile');
    $firstName = $this->faker->firstname;
    $name = $this->faker->name;


    $this->within('#userEditForm', function() use ($firstName, $name) {
        $this->type($firstName, 'firstname');
        $this->type($name, 'surname');
        $this->press('Speichern');
    });

    // here: how to wait for page reload ?
    $this->seePageIs('/user/profile');
    $this->see($firstName);
    $this->see($name);
}
```

*edit*

```
    $this->within('#userEditForm', function() use ($firstName, $lastname) {
        $this->type($firstName, 'firstname');
        $this->type($lastname, 'surname');
        $this->press('Speichern')
            ->seePageIs('/user/profile')
            ->see($firstName)
            ->see($lastname);
    });
```

also not working

Comment: Move your code in the within and chain it with the press (possibly). In general you don't seem to be waiting after the press is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a different one. Laravel *is* reloading the page when pressing the button.

In the view of the user profile, we use `Auth::user()` to display information.

When I do a

```
    Auth::setUser(Auth::user()->fresh());
```

in the user controller, it works.

Not a very satisfying solution - but the it makes the original question clear.