# Why do I have to reload Auth::user() when doing integration testing

Tags: php, laravel, testing, router

This is a follow up of [How to wait for a page reload in Laravel integration testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849082/how-to-wait-for-a-page-reload-in-laravel-integration-testing/39892032#39892032)

What I am doing is to edit a user's profile and then redisplay the view.

My profile action: (UserController)

```
public function profile(){
    return view('user/profile');
}
```

The view contains code like

```
{{ Auth::user()->firstname }}
```

now during my test, the old (unchanged) user data is displayed.

The test:

```
protected function editUserProfile()
{
    $this->visit('/user/profile');
    $firstName = $this->faker->firstname;
    $lastname = $this->faker->lastname;

    $this->within('#userEditForm', function() use ($firstName, $lastname) {
        $this->type($firstName, 'firstname');
        $this->type($lastname, 'surname');
        $this->press('Save')
            ->seePageIs('/user/profile')
            ->see($firstName)   # here the test fails
            ->see($lastname);
    });
}
```

When I change the UserController like this:

```
public function profile(){
    Auth::setUser(Auth::user()->fresh());
    return view('user/profile');
}
```

everything works fine.

Now I want to understand, why that is like this.

Why does the integration test behave differently to the browser in that case? Is there a better way to align that behavior so the tests do only fail if there is a "real problem"? Or is my code just bad?

Comment: What is the output of the failing test? Where does the `#userEditForm` submit to, is it ajax? If it is, I don't think you can use ajax with Laravel's basic testing suite, you will need to use selenium - take a look at this package: https://github.com/Modelizer/Selenium

Comment: It is not AJAX. The output is like "expected to see John", when I changed the username from Alice to John. So it is taking the old data. When I reload the Auth::user() all works fine

Comment: Why you don't use:

`$this->type($firstName, 'firstname')->type($lastname, 'surname')->markTestSkipped()->press('Save')->seePageIs('/user/profile')->see($firstName)   # here the test fails->see($lastname);`?

Comment: markTest Skipped should not be there ... I removed it

Comment: What are you using for integration testing?

Comment: @Sturm The normal controller tests which are provided with laravel. (simulating a HTTP request to the app itself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using `update (int $uid)` for the request?

The most likely explanation is that Laravel only uses a single application instance during the test. It's taking the input you give it, building a request object, and then sending it to the controller method. From here it can render the view and check that it contains your text.

In the authentication implementation once you call `Auth::user()` it doest one of two things:

- If no user is loaded it attempts to retrieve it from storage.
- If a user is already loaded it returns it.

Your update method (I'm guessing) is retrieving a new instance of the user from storage and updating it, not the cached one.

For example:

```
\Auth::loginUsingId(1234);
\Auth::user()->email; // 'user@example.com'

$user = \App\User::find(1234);
$user->email; // 'user@example.com';

$user->update(['email' => 'user2@example.com']);
$user->email; // 'user2@example.com'

\Auth::user()->email; // 'user@example.com'
```

Comment: But shouldn't Laravel reset the objects during the requests to provide proper isolation? Or is there a better way to write my own code?

Comment: @alex I would use something like Codeception to do this type of testing instead. Your code is fine, the test runner is lacking.